# Git not showing deleted lines in log

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with a remote designer deleting lines on pushes but the commit log not showing the line deletins, here a github pictures.

1. First picture shows 2 consecutive pushes
2. On the second picture you can see the .buy_button class of the previous commit, notice it includes a line "height: 25px" (almost the last line)
3. Picture of the commit log for coyr push, line height: 25px is deleted but its not shown as deleted it simple gone.
4. Picture of the .buy_button class of the coyr push, where the height: 25px is missing, there is no log of the line ever being deleted.

Why is the line deletion not appering in the log?

[image: This are 2 consecutive pushes]

[image: first push pick of class]

[image: first push log]

[image]

Comment: Please post a link to the github repo if possible (a picture does _NOT_ speak a thousand words in this case)

Comment: I just spent an eternity finding any of these commits in nivelstyle of ez-css; they aren't there?

Comment: sorry the github repository is private

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git lines getting deleted without notice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608682/git-lines-getting-deleted-without-notice)

Comment: Neither of those commits is the parent of the other one. I don't see any evidence that the diff *should* show that modification.

Comment: Also, why don't you examine all the commits in question in your *local* repository, with the full power of commands like `git blame <file>`, `git log -S`, `git show <commit>`, and `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`, as suggested in the answers to your other question?

Comment: @Jefromi: exactly my concerns :) The chances are 90% PEBCAK, 10% a strange cornercase (grafts, evil merge?). We cannot diagnose the 10% without a lot more detail.

Comment: I agree with @Jefromi.  That line should only show as deleted if it was present in `b2ac18`.  The contents of `db7213` aren't directly related.